# problem with UIRef in visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008, wix, wix3

Hi i'm having a problem with UIRef in Visual Studio when i try to add a wxs file.

```
<UIRef Id="MyWixUI_FeatureTree"/>
<UIRef Id="WixUI_ErrorProgressText" />
```

This is the error:
error LGHT0094 : Unresolved reference to symbol 'WixUI:MyWixUI_FeatureTree' in section 'Product:*'.

I don't know if i must make some changes on the VS settings.
or if I must add other reference.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify the element Id in your customized file "MyWixUI_FeatureTree.wxs":

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <UI Id="MyWixUI_FeatureTree">
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you create the UI Element "MyWixUI_FeatureTree"?  Is MyWixUI_FeatureTree really WixUI_FeatureTree?  If you reference an element, you need to make sure that element is actually in scope.

Comment: Well I copy the file "WixUI_FeatureTree.wxs" and change its name ("MyWixUI_FeatureTree.wxs"), after that I added the new file to my project (MyProject > Add > Existing Item) in VS 2008. ¿Is that enough?
?

Comment: After you renamed the wxs, did you update the UI element inside of it to change the Id from WixUI_FeatureTree to MyWixUI_FeatureTree?